# Postgresql Sub Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Saludos. Actualmente el query que estoy usando (sin variables) hace el trabajo necesario, pero ahora necesito agregar variables dentro del mismo.

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (a,b,c,d,FK_ID) SELECT a,b,c,d FROM tabla1
```

En la tabla2 tengo una columna fK_ID, como podria agregar este valor al query?

Comment: Sin explicar de donde proviene este valor, no es posible responder.

Comment: hola @sstan jonathan dio la respuesta

Comment: Ok, me alegra que entre ustedes se entendieron :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculando el campo, puede ser

```
  INSERT INTO tabla2 (a,b,c,d,FK_ID) SELECT a,b,c,d, (1) as fk_i FROM tabla1
```

Comment: Excelente @jonathan